Python doesn't see added module to the same dir
I added to my utils dir a new file that contains dict variable which I want to import into another file.
mapping.py
config = [
    {
        "filter_column": "SHOW_NAME",
        "horizons": [
            3,
            4,
            5,
            6
        ],
        "windows": [
            52
        ],
        "metrics": [
            "mean",
            "std",
            "min",
            "max",
            "quantile_25",
            "quantile_75",
            "trend"
        ]
    },.....
  ]

On deploy, my airflow stage2.py dag throws an error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'

Odd things is that env_config is recognized
Folder structure
README.rst
LICENSE
...
dags/utils/env_config.py
dags/utils/mapping.py
dags/utils/__init__.py
dags/stage2.py
...

stage2.py
import os
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.glue import GlueJobOperator
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup


sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

from utils.env_config import EnvironmentConfig  # noqa: E402
from utils.mapping import * # returns error


config = EnvironmentConfig(__file__)


That's weird, I can't reporduce your error...
Can you tell how you execute that script? From where are you running it?
Also, maybe try to list the directories in the path you added to sys.path, just to make sure your file is in there.
Something like:
print(os.listdir(sys.path[0]))
Have a look if your utils directory is in there.
But if I understood you correctly, your utils/env_config is recognized? That's very weird. Could you maybe show the content of env_config.py?

Odd stuff, I restarted VSC and pushed changes again to the repo. Both local and Airflow now see the new module.

I guess you can close your question then

Will leave tihs solution even if it's trivial.

Restart youre IDE
push your changes to Airflow's env and dag directory
Give Airflow few minutes to upload and refresh

